# SQL Server object creation

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE 
    TABLE_TA                                           
SET  
    ABM=A.ABM
FROM 
    (SELECT ID,ABM FROM FINAL_DATA )A                                          
INNER JOIN 
    TABLE_TA TB                                           
ON 
    A.ID=TB.ID
```

Someone who wrote this query in a procedure has left the company. This query is confusing me a bit about the table TABLE_TA can anyone tell me if this table's object will be created two times or one? The concern in query is in inner join he used Alias [TB] however updating table.

PS: Query may not be written logically correct as no need for an extra join however the point is creation of object as of now.

Comment: as far as I can tell this statement shouldn't work

Comment: You could write `update tb`. It will be the same. Nothing will be creatied here. Not clear what do you mean.

Comment: It's ok if you are using table name in `update` statement provided you are not repeating that table in joins, otherwise you'll have to use alias `TB`

Comment: [`UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx): "If the object being updated is the same as the object in the FROM clause and there is only one reference to the object in the FROM clause, an object alias may or may not be specified"

Comment: UPDATE TABLE_TA
SET TEST.Col1='454678'
FROM TABLE_TA TB
INNER JOIN TABLE_TA TB1 ON 
TABLE_TA.ID=TB1.ID
WHERE TABLE_TA.ID=1

can you tell me "Update Table_TA" is referring to which one Table_TA TB1or Table_TA TB, if only single object of Table_TA will be created ??

Answer (score 1):

The query you posted uses a "DERIVED TABLE" named "A". Derived Tables are Resultsets that you can use like a table. Have a look at this article to find out how they work: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/derived-table-vs-subquery/

I think the better written version of the statement you have is this:

```
UPDATE  TB
SET     TB.ABM = A.ABM
FROM    FINAL_DATA A
        INNER JOIN TABLE_TA TB ON A.ID = TB.ID
```

To explain: your query uses two tables (a derived table "A" and TABLE_TA "TB")..so the first line should be `UPDATE TB` instead of `UPDATE TABLE_TA`. What's more it's not necessary at all to use a derived table here. Simple join is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however i know query is unnecessarily wrapped with derived tables i am pretty much aware how derive table works.

Thing which is bothering me is " Update Table_TA and INNER JOIN Table_TA TB". I understand that if i do not use Alias then i can directly put table name instead, however in above query it seems me two queries are running for same table Table_TA. One is for update and one is for inner join and here update and Inner join are no where related to each other ( I guess so). Please correct me or if you can help with some technical perspective.

Comment: Ok so you're not so familiar with Update Statements? Short Explanation: In the FROM clause of your update statement can be any table you want, you will always just update ONE table -> the one you specify with "UPDATE TABLE_TA" in your example. Nothing will be created, nothing else then TABLE_TA will be updated

Comment: I think i would leave this here, lets see if someone can really help with the situation he anyone could really understand the point here.